# How c++ applications access hardware directly?

Tags: c++, operating-system, hardware, layer

I learnt that c++ has many low level access to hardware so we write drivers in c++. But when we write a normal desktop application in c++, will it be able to access hardware directly?
I'm asking this because desktop applications runs on the application layer. OS layer and OEM layer are there Between App layer and Hardware. then how can our application written in c++ access hardware directly?
please somebody explain me how exactly c++ desktop apps works.

thanks.

Comment: If your operating system is DOS, there is no difference between an application and a driver ...

Comment: C++ doesn't HAVE to use hardware directly. Desktop apps use some kind of GUI library or API.

Comment: Look at the history of Duff's device. He wanted a fast way to write data to a byte that mapped to a hardware device. He came up with a truly peculiar idea. This is one reason why `volatile` was put into the language; it was for locations that map to hardware devices and could change on their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, desktop applications have to go through the OS to access any resources, from extra memory to hard drives and sound chips.

In an embedded system, the hardware can be accessed directly, usually through a pointer.  So to write to a UART register, one would assign the address of the register to a pointer and dereference the pointer.

Many compiler libraries provide support for various platforms and embedded systems.  I'm using an IAR compiler for an ARM embedded system and programming with C++.  We don't use streams since we don't have terminal I/O.

**Edit 1: cout example**
For example, to print to the console, via `cout` or `printf`, the compiler provides a library that calls Operating System functions to display the text.

The Operating System function may send the text directly to the console or may pop up a "console window" and send the text to that.

The Console functions convert the text to bitmaps and send the bitmaps to the Graphics Controller.

The Graphics Controller displays the bitmap on the screen.